# The inertia group for the archimedeans places

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If $K/k$ is Galois (not necessarily finite), $w$ is an archimedean place of $K$, and $v$ is the place of $k$ 
below $w,$ then we define (the inertia group ) : $$T(w/v) =  \{\sigma\in  Gal(K/k) \hspace{2mm}|\hspace{2mm}\sigma w = w \}. 
$$
Question : how we prove that $|T(w/v)|=1 $ or $2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is the local field corresponding to $w$ (either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) then $T(w/v)$ is the group of the continuous automorphisms $\phi$ of $L$ s.t. $\phi(K)=K$  and $\phi(a)=a$ $\forall a\in k$. But the group of all continuous automophism of $L$ has at most 2 elements.

Comment: we must show that $T$ is nontrivial only when $v$ is real

Comment: I did not understand your proof

Comment: @Amine What I wrote says that $T$ is non-trivial iff $v$ is real and $w$ is complex.

Comment: I did not understand why $T(w/v)$  is the group of the continuous automorphisms of $L$ ??

Comment: @Amine You can show that an automorphism of a complete field is continuous if and only if it is an isometry. Now, clearly if $\sigma w= w$, then we have a unique continuous extension of $\sigma$ to $L_w/K_v$, which clearly still fixes $K_v$. Conversely, if we start with such a continuous automorphism, then by my statement earlier about the equivalence of continuity and isometry, the automorphism clearly restricts to an element of $T(w/v)$. This correspondence is clearly a bijection. But, then as user8268 points out, $L_w=\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}$ and $K_v=\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}$. From where

Comment: this follows from basic algebra. At least, this is how I interpret what @user8268 is saying--hopefully he can clarify.

Comment: @AlexYoucis it works thank you